# In Eagle, Why via is created in the distant location

Tags: eaglecad, autorouter

I'm using Eagle Autorouter. This works fine.

But sometimes via is created in the distant location.

Does anyone know the cause?

Image is using 10mil Grid.
Center-Top small one is the via of this case.

[image: Center-Top via is distant]

Comment: We can't really say why that via is there without knowing what it is connecting up to on the other layers.  It may make sense when looking at the other layers.  Also, check your keepout and restrict layers.

Answer (score 1):

Really hard to say.  Could just be an algorithmic featuren or something in your design rules.  Manually move it closer and do a design rule check to see what rule it breaks.

Comment: DRC Warning or Error don't appear even close manualy

Comment: Then its algorithmic, or maybe it got pushed out by some traces in an early iteration before optimization.  With Eagles autorouter (probably most autorouters), if it's important, lay it out manually before putting the autorouter to work, or fix it after the autorouting is done.  It's a pain to do it first (i.e., the right way) because ripping up to try again won't preserve your hand work.